# Json data is not binding properly in jqplot line chart

Tags: jquery, json, jqplot

Here is my code for jqplot chart.  I get a `no data specified` error in my browser console.  Or I get a blank chart with no line series drawn. Please help me to fix this issue.

```
var data1 = '[[[5.00,81.00],[7.20,80.00],[9.00,79.00],[10.80,72.00],[12.00,68.00],[15.00,49.00]],[[5.00,162.00],[7.20,160.00],[9.00,158.00],[10.80,144.00],[12.00,136.00],[15.00,98.00]],[[5.00,81.00],[5.00,162.00]],[[15.00,49.00],[15.00,98.00]],[[3.00,133.00],[3.90,126.00],[4.80,119.00],[6.00,107.00],[7.20,91.00],[9.00,61.00]],[[3.00,266.00],[3.90,252.00],[4.80,238.00],[6.00,214.00],[7.20,182.00],[9.00,122.00]],[[3.00,133.00],[3.00,266.00]],[[9.00,61.00],[9.00,122.00]]]';
var data ='{ "Values": [[[5.00, 81.00], [7.20, 80.00], [9.00, 79.00], [10.80, 72.00], [12.00, 68.00], [15.00, 49.00]], [[5.00, 162.00], [7.20, 160.00], [9.00, 158.00], [10.80, 144.00], [12.00, 136.00], [15.00, 98.00]], [[5.00, 81.00], [5.00, 162.00]], [[15.00, 49.00], [15.00, 98.00]], [[3.00, 133.00], [3.90, 126.00], [4.80, 119.00], [6.00, 107.00], [7.20, 91.00], [9.00, 61.00]], [[3.00, 266.00], [3.90, 252.00], [4.80, 238.00], [6.00, 214.00], [7.20, 182.00], [9.00, 122.00]], [[3.00, 133.00], [3.00, 266.00]], [[9.00, 61.00], [9.00, 122.00]]] }'
var data2= JSON.Parse('{ "Values": [[[5.00, 81.00], [7.20, 80.00], [9.00, 79.00], [10.80, 72.00], [12.00, 68.00], [15.00, 49.00]], [[5.00, 162.00], [7.20, 160.00], [9.00, 158.00], [10.80, 144.00], [12.00, 136.00], [15.00, 98.00]], [[5.00, 81.00], [5.00, 162.00]], [[15.00, 49.00], [15.00, 98.00]], [[3.00, 133.00], [3.90, 126.00], [4.80, 119.00], [6.00, 107.00], [7.20, 91.00], [9.00, 61.00]], [[3.00, 266.00], [3.90, 252.00], [4.80, 238.00], [6.00, 214.00], [7.20, 182.00], [9.00, 122.00]], [[3.00, 133.00], [3.00, 266.00]], [[9.00, 61.00], [9.00, 122.00]]] }');                  

var plot1 = $.jqplot('theChart', [data2.Values],
    {
         //dataRenderer:data1,
         title: 'Log Line',
         axes: { xaxis: { renderer: $.jqplot.LogAxisRenderer, ticks: [1, 10, 100, 1000] } },
         stackSeries: true,
         series: [{ color: '#5FAB78' }]
     });
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle ?

Comment: hi Moksh Shah, Thanks for the reply .. Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BSPriya/ebd71qwz/

Comment: am getting three type of values data1, data2 , data3 . If any of one of the json values  makes the jqplot line chart ill be fine for me .. Please help

Comment: Have updated my answer, verify it and do let me know if you still find any issue.

Comment: i have corrected the mistakes which u specified  in my fiddle . But still am getting the empty chart with no line series drawn. Please help

Comment: here is my updated fiddle where i corrected the json data as u said but still am getting the empty chart . Please help http://jsfiddle.net/BSPriya/ebd71qwz/12/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were multiple mistakes.

You have used `JSON.Parse` instead of `JSON.parse`.

You should wrap your code in `$(document).ready(function)`, so it can find dom element `i.e. your div`.

target Div name was also in-correct, you have mentioned `theChart` instead of `thechart` (its a case sensitive.)

**UPDATES**
Looks like it was an issue with your JSON format, anyways I've correct it and updated in fiddle, verify bellow fiddle.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ebd71qwz/2/)

Your over all code should look like this.

```
<div id="thechart" style="height:600px;width:95%;"></div>
```

Script:

```
var d = JSON.parse('{ "Values": [[[5.00, 81.00], [7.20, 80.00], [9.00, 79.00], [10.80, 72.00], [12.00, 68.00], [15.00, 49.00]], [[5.00, 162.00], [7.20, 160.00], [9.00, 158.00], [10.80, 144.00], [12.00, 136.00], [15.00, 98.00]], [[5.00, 81.00], [5.00, 162.00]], [[15.00, 49.00], [15.00, 98.00]], [[3.00, 133.00], [3.90, 126.00], [4.80, 119.00], [6.00, 107.00], [7.20, 91.00], [9.00, 61.00]], [[3.00, 266.00], [3.90, 252.00], [4.80, 238.00], [6.00, 214.00], [7.20, 182.00], [9.00, 122.00]], [[3.00, 133.00], [3.00, 266.00]], [[9.00, 61.00], [9.00, 122.00]]] }'); 
console.log(d.Values);
$(function(){
    $.jqplot('thechart', d.Values);
});
```

Your JSON format should look like this, when you pass it to `jqplot` function

```
[[[1, 2],[3,5.12],[5,13.1],[7,33.6],[9,85.9],[11,219.9]]
```

**UPDATE**

You need to remove extra square brackets:

```
var plot1 = $.jqplot('thechart', data3.Values,
```

instead of

```
var plot1 = $.jqplot('thechart', [data3.Values],
```

Comment: sorry i have corrected the code in the fiddle again.but am getting the empty chart .. Please help

Comment: @Dinesh92d, Have updated my  ans, let me know if you still face any issue, or if it does help then you may mark it as answer.

Comment: i have altered my json data as you said in the fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/BSPriya/ebd71qwz/12/  . But still am getting the empty chart.Please help

Comment: In your case, `stackSeries: true` causing a problem, if you make it to false `stackSeries: false`, then it will start working, you must be missing some default value for stack series, does it really required for your case?

Comment: i removed the stackseries attribute. but still it is showing  empty chart ... am binding multiple series data to the chart. Please help

Comment: @Dinesh92d, Check my updates,remove extra square bracket from your code.